# Show that $q: X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$ a subspace, and let $a_0 \in A$. Suppose that there exist $H:X \times I \to X$ continuous, such that $H(x,0)=x$ for every $x\in X$, $H(A \times I) \subseteq A$ and $H(a,1)=a_0$ for every $a\in A$. Show that $q: X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

So I have some ideas in mind but im not being able to put them together.

Because of the hypothesis given for $H$, we have that $H|_{A\times I}:A \times I \to A$ is a contraction, and therefore $A$ is conctractible, which implies it has the same homotopy type than a one point space $\{p\}$. So I think that $X/A$ and $X/ \{p\}$ should be homotopically equivalent (im not sure about this, i wasn't able to prove it, but its what my intuition suggests) and if this is true, then (i think) proving that $q_1 : X \to X/\{p\}$ is a homotopy equivalence should be easier.

However, Im not being able to write formally any of this ideas. Are there even true?

Comment: I'm not sure you have your statement correct. $q$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: The map $H_{X\times\{1\}} = H_1: X\to X$ is a map that factors through $X/A$, $X\to X/A \to X$. So, then you have a candidate for a homotopy inverse $X/A \to X$, and one of the compositions is already homotopic to the identity $X$ via $H$. What remains is to show that $X/A\to X \to X/A$ is homotopic to the identity $X/A \to X/A$. Here you want to pass the homotopy $H$ to the quotient, and you will need to see that $I$ satisfies some technical hypotheses to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

The question was answered in Justin Young's comment.

The map $f' : X \to X, f'(x) = H(x,1)$, has the property $f'(a) = a_0$ for all $a \in A$ and thus induces a map $f : X/A \to X$ such that $f q = f'$. But $f' \simeq id_X$. The map $H$ satisfies $H(a,t) \in A$ for all $(a,t) \in A \times I$. Hence it induces a function $H' :X/A \times I \to X/A$ such that $qH = H'(q \times id_I)$. Since $I$ is compact, $q \times id_I$ is again a quotient map and we conclude that $H'$ is continuous. We have $H'([x],0) = qH(x,0) = q(x) = [x]$ and $H'([x],1) = qH(x,1) = qf'(x) = qf'q(x) = qf([x])$. Thus $id_{X/A} \simeq qf$.